# How to return nested xml from web service

Tags: c#

I am generating below xml from SQL stored procedure and I want to return the same from web service method. when I tried to read in to dataset and return it its displaying whole thing as one string.

```
<HrDetails EmployeeLastName="NEUHAUS" EmployeeFirstName="abc" EmployeeID="00182838" ID="45685325" OrganizationCode="H2254" Division="hhs" OfficialPositionTitle="CLINICAL FELLOW" OccupationalSeries="0602"   AnualPay="124000.0000">
  <abcs>
    <abc>
      <Amount>0.00</Amount>
      <Date>08/07/2018</Date>
    </abc>
  </abcs>
  <xyzs>
    <xyz>
      <Amount>0</Amount>
      <Date>07/01/2018</Date>
    </xyz>
    <xyz>
      <Amount>0</Amount>
      <Date>01/07/2018</Date>
    </xyz>
    <xyz>
      <Amount>0</Amount>
      <Date>08/07/2018</Date>
    </xyz>
  </xyzs>
</HrDetails>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So send it back as a string then set your xml document. `XmlDocument.LoadXml(yourXmlString);` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument.loadxml?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: @william xifaras So, I have all the data in one table(SQL database). and I want to create a web service with xml output. the output should be nested(few columns are grouped and return as a sets.

Comment: @sravi Sets of what? Objects? So you want to create classes out of the XML elements?

Answer (score 0):

Using xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string response = File.ReadAllText(FILENAME);
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(response);

            XElement hrDetails = doc.Root;

            HR hr = new HR()
            {
                employeeLastName = (string)hrDetails.Attribute("EmployeeLastName"),
                employeeFirstName = (string)hrDetails.Attribute("EmployeeFirstName"),
                employeeID = (string)hrDetails.Attribute("EmployeeID"),
                id = (string)hrDetails.Attribute("ID"),
                organizationCode = (string)hrDetails.Attribute("OrganizationCode"),
                division = (string)hrDetails.Attribute("Division"),
                officialPositionTitle = (string)hrDetails.Attribute("OfficialPositionTitle"),
                occupationalSeries = (string)hrDetails.Attribute("OccupationalSeries"),
                anualPay = (decimal)hrDetails.Attribute("AnualPay")
            };
            hr.accounts = hrDetails.Elements().Select(x => new Accounts() {
                 name = x.Name.LocalName, accounts = x.Elements().Select(y => new Account() {
                    name = y.Name.LocalName,
                    amount = (decimal)y.Element("Amount"),
                    date = (DateTime)y.Element("Date")
                }).ToList()
            }).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class HR
    {
        public string employeeLastName { get; set;}
        public string employeeFirstName  { get; set;}
        public string employeeID  { get; set;}
        public string id  { get; set;}
        public string organizationCode  { get; set;}
        public string division  { get; set;}
        public string officialPositionTitle  { get; set;}
        public string occupationalSeries  { get; set;}
        public decimal anualPay  { get; set;}
        public List<Accounts> accounts { get; set; }
    }
    public class Accounts
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public List<Account> accounts { get; set; }
    }
    public class Account
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public decimal amount { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }

    }

}
```